# C# visual studio asp.net adding an item to a list attribute

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I am currently working on a project to model a bikestore.  In my 'Order' object, I have a lis object for the Bike items on the order.  How would I add bikes to this list?  I.E I want to display a list of availiable bikes in the Create view, an add one or more of them to the order.

My Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "OrderNumber,CustomerName,OrderDate,PickupDate,TotalCost,PaymentMethod")] Order order)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Orders.Add(order);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(order);
        }
```

My Inventory model

```
public class Inventory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
        public int? StoreId { get; set; }

        public string Model { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Decimal InventoryCost { get; set; }

        public Decimal RecSalePrice { get; set; }

        public Decimal SalePrice { get; set; }

        public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }

        public virtual BikeCategory Category { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }







    }
```

My Order model:

```
namespace BikeStore.Models
{

    public class Order
    {
        public Order()
        {
            OrderedItems = new List<Inventory>();
        }

        public string CustomerName { get; set; } //FROM CONTROLLER User.Identity.Name

        public virtual List<Inventory> OrderedItems { get; set; }


         [Key, DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
```

In the create view for orders:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Order</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PickupDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PickupDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PickupDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TotalCost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalCost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TotalCost, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentMethod, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PaymentMethod, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentMethod, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use Entity Framework's Entity Model classes as ViewModels. The two are distinct concepts despite them both having "model" in their name.

Comment: Where exactly do you see a ViewModel here?

Comment: Not clear what you question is. Are you wanting to display a list of available bikes in the `Order` view so that you can select one of more to include in the order? What is the relevance of all this code? What does you `Delete()` method for example have to do with the question?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, Exactly.

Comment: Start by deleting all the irrelevant code from your question and we might be inclined to look at it :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Done.  Not really sure what is and isn't irrelevant.  Did my best.

Comment: OK, Now you need to add the model for `Inventory` (I assume that's the collection of available bikes?). And what sort of UI do you want - a list of bikes with an associated checkbox it indicate which bikes the user wants to order?

Comment: @StephenMuecke done. A instance of the Inventory class is just a bike.  And a checkbox would be good.

Comment: Need a break for a while but I'll add an answer in an hour or so. (I assume you do have a separate table for OrderItems)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I do.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating view models to represent what you want to display/edit in the view (add display and validation attributes as appropriate)

```
public class InventoryVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
public class OrderVM
{
  public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
  public List<InventoryVM> Inventory { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `CustomerName`, `OrderDate` and `Total` are not appropriate (you don't want a user editing these - they should be set in the POST method immediately before saving the order). Not sure what `PickupDate` represents but if its the actual date then that's not appropriate either (it would be set separately when the order is collected). I would also suggest that `PaymentMethod` be an enum or collection of `PaymentType`'s and that you and use a dropdownlist in the view for selection.

Then the GET method would be

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  // Get all available bikes, for example
  var inventory = db.Inventory;
  OrderVM model = new OrderVM
  {
    Inventory = inventory.Select(i => new
    {
      ID = i.ID,
      Name = i.Model // modify this to suit what you want to display in the view
    }).ToList()
  };
  return View(model);
}
```

And in the view

```
@model yourAssembly.OrderVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Inventory.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Inventory[i].ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Inventory[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Inventory[i].IsSelected, Model.Inventory[i].Name)
  }
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PayentMethod)
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

And the POST method would be

```
public ActionResult Create(OrderVM model)
{
  // Initialize a new Order and map properties from view model
  var order = new Order
  {
    CustomerName = User.Identity.Name,
    OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
    ....
    PaymentMethod = model.PaymentMethod
  }
  // Save the order so that you now have its `ID`
  IEnumerable<int> selectedItems = model.Inventory.Where(i => i.IsSelected).Select(i => i.ID);
  foreach(var item in selectedItems)
  {
    // You have not shown the model for this so just guessing
    var orderItem = new OrderItem{ OrderID = order.Id, InventoryId = item };
    db.OrderItems.Add(orderItem);
  }
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Side notes:

1. If you want to be able to allow users to select more that one of any
   item, the you could change `bool IsSelected` to say `int Quantity`
2. If you you want to display additional information about the items,
   say `Description` and `Cost` you can include additional properties
   in the `InventoryVM` view model and display them with
   `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Inventory[i].Description)`
3. If you want to display a total cost for all selected items in the
   view, you will need to use javascript/jquery
4. If `ModelState` could be invalid, you will need to repopulate the
   properties of `InventoryVM` before you return the view (as shown
   only the `ID` and `IsSelected` properties post back) or include
   hidden inputs for the other properties in the view

Comment: Thank you!  However, I.m getting a runtime error at  IEnumerable<InventoryVM> selectedItems = order.Inventory.Where(i => i.IsSelected);  I keep getting a ArgumentNullException there.  Would you happen to know whats going on with that?

Comment: Oops - left of the `.Select(i => i.ID)` bit - see edit (and it is `IEnumerable<int>` not `IEnumerable<InventoryVM>`

Comment: And its `model.Inventory` not `order.Inventory`

Comment: Appears to work, but Still getting a ArgumentNullException, Same place.  Any idea on what could be wrong?