# C# visual studio asp.net adding an item to a list attribute NullAttribute Exception:

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I am currently working on a project to model a bikestore. In my 'Order' object, I have a list object for the Bike items on the order.  Thanks to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092459/c-sharp-visual-studio-asp-net-adding-an-item-to-a-list-attribute/33093195?noredirect=1#comment54004870_33093195), I have almost implemented a selectList where I can add one or more bikes to an order.  However, I have run into a ArgumentNullException on the following line of code in my Post Controller method:

```
IEnumerable<int> selectedItems = model.Inventory.Where(i => i.IsSelected).Select(i => i.Id);
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and how to fix it?

My Create View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @foreach(var i in Model.Inventory)
            {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Inventory.First(x=>x.Id==i.Id).Id)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Inventory.First(x => x.Id == i.Id).IsSelected)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Inventory.First(x => x.Id == i.Id).IsSelected, Model.Inventory.First(x => x.Id == i.Id).Name)
            }
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PaymentMethod)
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </div>
```

My Order View Model:

```
namespace BikeStore.Models
{
    public class OrderVM
    {
        public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<InventoryVM> Inventory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Inventory View Model:
namespace BikeStore.Models

```
{
    public class InventoryVM
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Get Controller Method:

```
// GET: Orders/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var inventory = db.StoreInventory;
            OrderVM model = new OrderVM
            {
                Inventory = (IEnumerable<InventoryVM>)inventory.Select(i => new InventoryVM { Id = i.Id, Name = i.Model })
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

My Post Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PaymentMethod, Inventory")]OrderVM model)
        {
            var Order = new Order
            {
                CustomerName = User.Identity.Name,
                OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                PaymentMethod = model.PaymentMethod,
                TotalCost=0

            };
            IEnumerable<int> selectedItems = model.Inventory.Where(i => i.IsSelected).Select(i => i.Id);
            foreach(var item in selectedItems)
            {
      // You have not shown the model for this so just guessing
                var orderItem = new OrderedItem { OrderId = Order.OrderNumber, InventoryId = item };
                db.OrderedItems.Add(orderItem);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(model);

        }
```

My OrderedItem Model:

```
namespace BikeStore.Models
{
    public class OrderedItem
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int InventoryId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Order Model:

```
public class Order
    {
        public Order()
        {
            OrderedItems = new List<Inventory>();
        }

        public string CustomerName { get; set; } //FROM CONTROLLER User.Identity.Name

        public virtual List<Inventory> OrderedItems { get; set; }
        //public virtual List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime PickupDate { get; set; }

         [Key, DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }

        public Store StoreOrderedFrom { get; set; }

        public Decimal TotalCost { get; set; }

        public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop. Refer back to my answer to your last question. It needs to be a `for` loop. And in the `OrderVM` model it needs to be `List<InventoryVM> Inventory` Check the html your now generating compared to using the `for` loop and you will understand why your code is not working

Comment: @StephenMuecke If I do that I run into problems.  I cannot convert between a IQueryable and a List for the line Inventory = inventory.Select(i => new InventoryVM { Id = i.Id, Name = i.Model }).  Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Yes you can - just add `.ToList()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Okay.  I no longer get errors, but now when I click "Create"  the selected Item's name changes it's name to "IsSelected", and a Order is not created.  Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for all your help, BTW.

Comment: What do you mean the _selected Item's name changes it's name to "IsSelected"_? Your not doing anything with the name.

Comment: Oh I see. You dont return the view when its been saved. You redirect somewhere else. And if you read the notes (point 4) I made in my last answer you will understand

Comment: @StephenMuecke Before clicking "Create":  [x]Red Ryder [ ]White Streak After clicking "create": [x]IsSelected [ ] White Streak

Comment: I assume you did not get a chance to read my last comment?

Comment: I dont' t understand.  What do you mean by 'repopulate the properties of InventoryVM before you return?

Comment: You are currently rendering form controls for the `ID` and `IsSelected` properties only. There is no form control for the `Name` property (e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Inventorty[i].name)` so nothing is posted back to the controller so its `null`. If you need to return the view (and you should only ever do that if `ModelState` is invalid), the you must repopulate the name property before returning the view or include a hidden input so its bound to the property. Please read the notes in my last answer.

Comment: And please inspect the html you were previously generating compared to the html your now generating so you can understand how model binding works.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you've lost me.  So in order to get this to work correctly, I have to put @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Inventorty[i].name) in the loop?

Comment: If you want to bind the `Name` property, then yes, or else read the values from the repository again.

Comment: Ok, it no longer does the "switch name to IdSelected" thing, but the Order still has not been created.  Any ideas?

Comment: No where in your code have you added the order to the db context and saved it. You need to go back and study the answer I gave you. You have ignored the line _// Save the order so that you now have its ID_ - for example it might be `db.Orders.Add(order); db.SaveChanges();` but I cant guess every detail of you project :)

Comment: I dunno, you've done a really good job of it so far :)

Comment: It works!  Thank you!

Comment: Since no one can give an answer except to say _follow the original answer_, I have marked it as a duplicate.